# changing scaling_governor on android device

Tags: java, android, linux, cpu, frequency

hi guys im trying to change the scaling_governor on android device using this code

```
String[] args = {"/system/bin/echo userspace >", "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor"};
ProcessBuilder cmd1;  
cmd1 = new ProcessBuilder(args);

Process process = cmd1.start();
```

but nothing has changed :( what am i doing wrong??

Answer (score 1):

Is your program running as `root` (`euid == 0`)?

The scaling governor is restricted to writing by only root:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 2011-01-30 13:45 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
```